# Flatlist ScrollToItem with reference to Item ID

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

so my API calls will return every Item ID that the flatlist has to render. How can i possibly set the initial scrollToItem with reference to the Item ID i got from my api calls? I can only scroll to the index of the flatlist right now, but can't possibly scroll to the exact item by calling it's properties.

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.dataSource}
    renderItem={
    ({item}) => (
        <VoucherList item={item} navigation={this.props.navigate} />
        )
    }
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
    onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
    initialScrollIndex={2}
    getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
  />
```

Above are my code right now where i set the initial scroll index is 2. I want to scroll to the props, for example if the Item has the ID of 2, i would like to reference it to the ID.

Any help would be appreciated, or perhaps a sample code.

Answer (score 1):

`FlatList` does not have what you need. But you can work around that by providing the `initialScrollIndex` as a function that returns the index `FlatList` needs. It really depends on what your data source contains. You would need the data before the `FlatList` is mounted as the `initialScrollIndex` will be processed as soon as possible.